# Can I access device data from the shader without using a cbuffer?

Tags: directx, hlsl

Is there a way to access data, such as current resolution, from the shader without passing it specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolution of the rendertarget is not available, you need to pass it explicitly.

Resolution of an input texture is in DirectX 10+, you can use GetDimensions

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509693(v=vs.85).aspx